# Difference between modelname.new and modelname.create in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am using the Rails console I can type either:

```
Paper.new(name: "deva", body: "testing")
Paper.create(name: "deva", body: "testing")
```

and it seems like the same result. What exactly is the difference between `.new` and `.create`?

Answer (score 2):

aa = Paper.new(name: "deva",body: "testing")
In the above case you have to do do .save then only it will generate the id for that record if is valid data, else it will do roll back and it not stored in database.

and here you also can add more field which is in your data table like
aa.contact_no = "1234"
aa.save

Paper.create(name: "deva",body: "testing")
In this case it will try to create the record at the same time and go through the validations.

Comment: while i'm adding datas like aa.contact_no = "1234" will it store the data in Paper database?

Comment: if it has that data field in the table. or after that you have to do aa.save

Answer (score 1):

`new` only initialize the object and do not save the object in the database

`create` initializes as well as save it if all validations are met.

for help see this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class

Comment: if we using .new method we want to use .save method to store data in database  right?

Comment: yes you have to call explicitly `.save` on that object to save it.